# how disable php engine in template views

Tags: php, codeigniter

I use template parser class to render my views. Because views are editable for some users I need disable php interpreter in views.

What is way to do it?

Regards!

**EDIT:**

- I added .htaccess file in views directory:

```
AddType text/plain .php
```

- I extended CI_Loader replacing php begin mark (added slashes before php mark) in _ci_load() function.

Now php is not working in views.

Answer (score 0):

(assuming you're using Apache)

You could save the files with **.tpl** extensions and add something like...

```
AddType text/plain .tpl
```

... to your Apache httpd.conf file (or .htaccess probably).

It **won't** of course prevent people from adding PHP code in the template if they feel like it but it should mean that that code won't be interpreted if the files are viewed on the web-server; however that leaves any raw PHP code entered in those files available in plain text to anyone who finds the URI (www.yoursite.ext/templates/a_template.tpl) - which could be very bad if, for some obscure reason it's got something like `define('DB_PASSWORD', "DBP@55w0rd");` in there (OK that would be very wrong but you get the point).

**A better solution** would be to store the **tpl** files outside the web-tree, or inside a folder protected with an .htaccess `Deny from all` - your PHP scripts will still be able to pull them in *but* they'll not be accessible directly to anyone over http, so any PHP inside your views will never be interpreted as it'll never be accessible.

Alternatively, if you're flexible on your view engine, take a look at PHPTAL : http://phptal.org/

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your problem.

Does your parser recognize PHP in templates? if so - how disabling will help? If no - what does PHP do with your templates at all? Do they have .php extension?